# Sending command to minecraft server running in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a minecraft server running in a docker and I want to execute a command in the server from the host.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  spigot:
    image: openjdk:8
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "25565:25565"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./spigot
        target: /server
    working_dir: /server
    command: java -jar spigot-1.8.8.jar
```

Running `docker-compose exec spigot echo "help" > /dev/pts/0` enters the command into the server but it wont get executed.

Comment: As we are talking about a Minecraft server, the solution I found for now is using [RCON](https://wiki.vg/RCON) to execute commands

Answer (score 1):

You can use RCON to send commands to your server. Open it by typing the following in your hosts console/terminal.

```
sudo docker exec -i [minecraft_server_name] rcon-cli
```

e.g.: my [minecraft_server_name] would be minecraft_minecraft_1

Now you can write your commands like you would in Minecraft itself. For example whitelist a player `whitelist add [playername]` or change difficulty `difficulty hard`

To close RCON just press CTRL+C

Answer (score 0):

You have set

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

Did you try `docker attach spigot`, then you are on the server console.

Then use ctrl-p ctrl-q to detach.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that I can acces the process via that command, but I just want to send a single command without opening the console.

Comment: This does not work for me. Both these options are set to true, but whenever I attach and run `help` it just does nothing and keeps running. Ctrl-p ctrl-q also does not work.